# Bootstrap Nav-bar multicolorido

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav-bar

Tenho como deixar meu nav-bar multicolorido?

Por exemplo, metade de uma cor, metade de outra?

Eu quero fazer algo [nesse estilo](http://jsfiddle.net/3brhrrgf/4/embedded/result) mas não quero essas marcas de degradê.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei bem como funciona o bootstrap mas minha sugestão é que você trabalhe com linear gradient.

**Exemplo em um menu simples:**

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #F00 50%); /* Para mais cores, adicione uma virgula, seguido do código HEX e a porcentagem de forma equivalente entre elas */
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  margin: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px bold "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

**Exemplo utilizando o bootstrap com o código de menu de exemplo contido na documentação (Basta sobrescrever a regra padrão):**

```css
.navbar-default {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #F00 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/3brhrrgf/1/

**SEGUINDO SEU NOVO PEDIDO**: http://jsfiddle.net/3brhrrgf/9/

**Mais sobre linear-gradient:** [Linear Gradient](http://tableless.com.br/como-usar-gradient-no-css-de-forma-consciente/)

Comment: Eu quero fazer algo nesse estilo https://jsfiddle.net/3brhrrgf/4/embedded/result/
Mas nao quero essas marcas de degrade. Sabe como resolver?

Comment: Não pois este é o comportamento normal da propriedade, afinal é um degrade.

Comment: Mas no seu exemplo nao tem essas marcas. Nao tem nenhuma propriedade que altere o range do degrade?

Comment: Assim ta bom: http://jsfiddle.net/3brhrrgf/9/  ?

Comment: Infelizmente não, quando você altera para uma resolução de browser ele distorce. Tem alguma outra solução que não envolva gradient?

Comment: Ele se adapta como deve ser. E não, não tenho. Siga a outra resposta abaixo, talvez funcione.

Comment: Mesmo com o problema do degradê, foi a resposta que mais me ajudou.

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo dentro da navbar, duas áreas e a cada uma delas atribuir uma cor que faça anulação da côr principal ( a default da navbar ).

Em html:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="area1">
           /*Conteudo da primeira metade da navbar*/
       </div>
       <div class="area2">
           /*Conteudo da segunda metade da navbar*/
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

No css:

```
.area1{
background-color: red !important;
width: 50%;
float: left;
}

.area2{
background-color: blue !important;
width: 50%;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Quero fazer algo nesse estilo jsfiddle.net/3brhrrgf/4/embedded/result sem as marcas de degradê. Pode me mostrar como seria feito?

Comment: marcas de degrade?como assim?

Comment: Deixa, já consegui usando outra solução, obrigado.